# Swift - Resize collection view after Master View is closed

Tags: ios, swift

I have an split view on my project and a button that when clicked minimizes the master view. I'm minimizing the master view using this function for the button:

```
  @IBAction func newProposalBtnWasClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode == .automatic {
      splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
    } else {
      splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .automatic
    }
    var sub = self.childViewControllers[1] as! ProductsPlatesViewController
    sub.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
```

When the master view is setted to .primaryHidden my cells becomes wrong spaced:

In the collection view View controller I defined that function:

[image: before]
[image: after]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                             sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode == .primaryHidden {
      return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/3.0 - 10.0, height: self.view.frame.height/4.0 - 10.0)
    }

    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width/2.0 - 10.0, height: self.view.frame.height/4.0 - 10.0)
  }
```

But the function apparently is not being called when I press the button. How can I make the function to be called and redefine the number of cells per row?

**EDIT:**

I changed put reloadData() method on my button action function (code edited above).

my sizeForItemAtIndexPath function still the same. The result I get is:

[image]
[image]

It's like its aplying the sizeForItemAtIndexPath before the preferedDisplayMode is setted, but in the code this is made before the call for reloadData() function. Where I went wrong?

Comment: When you hide the master view, does `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` get called?

Comment: No. I put a break point there. The method ins't called. I don't know how to force the call. I tried setNeedsDisplay and setNeedsLayout already :(

Comment: Try reloading the collectionView. `setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` account for auto layout only. This issue is related to `collectionView's FlowLayout`.

Comment: Post updated. Please check. Thanks :D